# John and I went to the café with two of our other friends

Tags: meaning

I'm trying to understand some interlinguistic differences in the use of *other* and its equivalents. I wondered if the sentence above strikes other English speakers as odd - the meaning is perfectly clear, but do you think you would say this spontaneously?

Comment: In that sentence I would leave out the word "other".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether the sentence sounds odd or not depends on the context. If I make the comment out of the blue to my interlocutor, it would probably sound odd. This is because the word *other* implies shared knowledge as to the first alternative.

If on the other hand the comment is preceded by something like: *John and I were thinking of asking Sid and Nancy*, in which the alternative is stated, then the *other* is justified.

But then in the stated context you have the problem of the superfluous repetition of *John and I*:

> ?John and I were thinking of asking Sid and Nancy, but John and I went
>   to the café with two of our other friends.

In summary, standing alone as a spontaneous comment the statement sounds odd to me,  a native speaker. You should omit the superfluous and possibly ambiguous word *other*.

Comment: IOW for you the *other* has to refer to someone who is a friend of John's and also a friend of mine, which can't really be said of John or myself - right? Cf. *I went to the café with John and one of my other friends*.

Comment: Right!  _two of our other friends_ implies to me: _other friends of both of us_. Your _cf._ sentence sounds fine but obviously has a different meaning.

Comment: Thanks. I wondered if I was being pedantic but it seems not. It seems that French permits this structure on the basis that for John, I am the first friend so there can be *others*, and mutatis mutandis for me. I haven't quite got to the bottom of it yet but thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks for the interesting insight into how French works differently. German, on the other hand, works the same way as English.